# MongoDb join 2 collections by _id and select result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I would like to select from this 2 collections the users with moderator roles.

USERS collection

```json
[
  {
    _id: "701",
    username: "user1",
    roles: [
      "617",
      "618"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "702",
    username: "user2",
    roles: [
      "617"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "703",
    username: "user3",
    roles: [
      "617",
      "619"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "704",
    username: "user4",
    roles: [
      "617",
      "619"
    ]
  }
]
```

ROLES collection

```json
[
  {
    _id: "617",
    name: "simpleuser"
  },
  {
    _id: "618",
    name: "admin"
  },
  {
    _id: "619",
    name: "moderator"
  }
]
```

In SQL would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USERS
JOIN ROLES ON ROLE_ID = USER_ROLES
WHERE ROLE_NAME = "moderator"
```

I can not figure it out with mongodb mongoose. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `$lookup` with pipeline like this:

- First `$lookup` matching the role id using `$in` because it is in an array and `$eq` to compare the role.
- This generates a field called `roles` which overwrite the existing field (you can change the name if you don't want to overwrite) and then uses `$match` to match the documents where the roles is not empty (i.e. there is a coindicence with roles table).

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "roles",
      "let": {"roles": "$roles"},
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {"$in": ["$_id","$$roles"]},
                {"$eq": ["$name","moderator"]}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "roles"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "roles": {"$ne": [] }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xPRVoJxOosJ)

Using mongoose you can do:

```
const result = await yourCollection.aggregate(/*the query*/)
res.status(200).send(result) // or whatever
```

Or using callback

```
yourCollection.aggregate(/*the query*/).then(result => {res.status(200).send(result)})
```

Also, you can use `$project` stage to send fields you want to the frontend, for example, to send only `username` you can use [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UWzsS-FVA_U)

Comment: This works in this example, thank you very much. But how can i save the result in a variable or send to the frontend? res.send(????) I tried like result = your code, then console.log(result), but im getting some model like Aggregate {
  _pipeline: [ { '$lookup': [Object] }, { '$match': [Object] } ],
  _model: Model { User },
  options: {}
}

Comment: Updated! Hope it helps. I think you are forgetting about `async/await`.

Comment: Thank you. It works now, the problem was with the another collection. I wanted to add to your code with an exported mongoose model, but its not needed, just simply use the collection name.